# No idea to how to get this design and make it responsive tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to achieve this look using tailwind css and next js to code this component [sketch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKAVM.jpg) and I don't know how to do it

I can't for any reason get the images in a grid and if i did they won't display just the alt

this is what i tried to do so far

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import { WOM_1, WOM_2, WOM_3, WOM_4, WOM_5, WOM_6, WOM_7, WOM_8 } from 'public/images/index.js';

const ImageCard = ({ image, alignment, cardWidth, cardHeight }) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                {cardWidth && cardHeight ? (
                    <Image
                        src={image}
                        alt=""
                        width={cardWidth}
                        height={cardHeight}
                        layout="fixed"
                        className={`object-cover object-center overflow-hidden`}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <Image
                        src={image}
                        alt=""
                        width={193}
                        height={179}
                        layout="fixed"
                        className={`object-cover object-center `}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>


    );
};

const WallOfMemories = () => {
    const imageInfo1 = [
        { image: WOM_1, alignment: '0px' },
        { image: WOM_2, alignment: '-20px' },
        { image: WOM_3, cardWidth: '193px', cardHeight: '179px', alignment: '20px' },
        { image: WOM_4, alignment: '-20px' },
    ];
    const imageInfo2 = [
        { image: WOM_5, alignment: '0px' },
        { image: WOM_6, cardWidth: '193px', cardHeight: '179px',alignment: '20px' },
        { image: WOM_7, alignment: '-20px' },
        { image: WOM_8, alignment: '0px' },
    ];
    // display the images in a grid of 4x2 in the center of the page
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
                {imageInfo1.map((image, index) => (
                    <ImageCard
                        key={index}
                        image={image.image}
                        alignment={image.alignment}
                        cardWidth={image.cardWidth}
                        cardHeight={image.cardHeight}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center w-full h-full">
                {imageInfo2.map((image, index) => (
                    <ImageCard
                        key={index}
                        image={image.image}
                        alignment={image.alignment}
                        cardWidth={image.cardWidth}
                        cardHeight={image.cardHeight}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default WallOfMemories;
```

i think there is no need to tell that i am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

you should use `object-scale-down` class name for `Image` component:

```
<Image
                       src={image}
                        alt=""
                        width={cardWidth}
                        height={cardHeight}
                        layout="fixed"
                        className={`object-scale-down object-center overflow-hidden`}
                    />
```

`object-cover` covers the screen all the time and it does not scale, instead it shrinks the image